# Is there a way to use the @ character in a MySQL query from a C# .net program without using parametrised queries?

Tags: c#, mysql

Is there a way to use the @ character in a MySQL query from a C# .net program without using parametrised queries?

So for example in the following program

```
String s = 
@"LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE C:\foo.txt'  
INTO TABLE Bar
(idFoo, @baa)
SET  
baa = nullif(@baa,'')
";
MySqlCommand myCommand = new MySqlCommand(s, myConnection);
MySqlDataReader myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
```

@baa is treated like a parameter. ie: as one would use when calling

```
myCommand.Parameters.Add("@baa", SqlDbType.VarChar );
```

However in this case I do not want @baa to be a parameter. How do I write this?

Comment: just dont add the parameter, it will be treated as normal text!

Comment: I think last time I didn't provide the parameter I got an error..

Comment: try `@@` or `\@` one of them must escape it. i do not have mysql installed that i can test.

Comment: Just figured it out now, I needed to add "allow user variables" to the connection string

Comment: although, as I have framed my question, you have given the correct answer

Comment: "allow user variables" link: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18071813/3175562

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL uses the back-tick character to quote tokens with spaces or other special characters.  This is used for example to handle field names with spaces, etc.

So in your code, where you want `@baa` to refer to a field name, place back-tick characters around the name like so: `` `@baa` ``

Comment: already tried that, I needed to add allow user variables to the connection string

Comment: That wasn't clear from the question.  What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Loading the data into a table, was originally doing this with insert statements except it took too long (about an hour). It only takes a few seconds now.

Comment: @sav Have you tried the SqlBulkCopy class?  I've used it to insert thousands of records in well under a second.  Check out this blog: http://www.adathedev.co.uk/2010/02/sqlbulkcopy-bulk-load-to-sql-server.html