# .NET MySqlCommand @ placeholder conflicted with MySQL variable

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, vb.net

This is a sample SQL for the sake of this question. (The actual SQL is more complicated than this one)

```
SET @HELLO = 1;
SELECT @HELLO;
```

As you can see. `@HELLO` is a MySQL variable, but .NET MySQLCommand treats as if it is a placeholder than need to bind value. Is there anyway I can use MySQL variable with .NET?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the following [MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Parameter ‘@id’ must be defined](http://blog.tjitjing.com/index.php/2009/05/mysqldatamysqlclientmysqlexception-parameter-id-must-be-defined.html)

Which states

> Finally, I  found that this was indeed a change in the .Net Connector.
>   (I’m not sure what version number but starting from 5.2.0 would be my
>   guess)  Starting from version 5.2.2 of the Connector you should add
>   the Allow User Variables=True Connection String Setting in order to
>   use User Defined Variables in your SQL statements.
>
> Example of Connection String:
>
> ```
>  Database=testdb;Data Source=localhost;User Id=root;Password=hello;Allow User Variables=True
> ```

Comment: Adding "Allow User Variables=True" works like a charm. Thanks.

Comment: and I need 4 more minutes before I can make this as answer.